# problem with lim of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, cesaro-summable

i don't know how to prove this lim..i thought i can use Cesaro-Stolz here but i can't..:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty }a_{n}= \infty \\
b_{n}= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }a_{k}
$$
how to prove that :
$\lim_{n \to \infty }b_{n}= \infty$

Comment: You'll want $b_n$ to have something to do with the partial sums, not $\frac1n \cdot \text{value of series}$...

Comment: As remarked by Alex, your expression is $\;b_n:=\frac1n\cdot\infty\;$ and this makes no sense. Check this.

Answer (score 1):

Of course,
$$
b_{n}= \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^na_k.
$$
For every $C$ there exists some $N$ such that for every $n\gt N$, $a_n\geqslant C$. Hence, for every $n\geqslant N$,
$$
b_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^Na_k+\frac1n\sum_{k=N+1}^na_k\geqslant\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^Na_k+\frac{n-N}nC.
$$
The first term on the RHS converges to zero when $n\to\infty$, since $N$ is fixed once $C$ is chosen. What does the second term on the RHS converge to? Can you conclude?

Comment: first, tnx! i dont understand how you got the bn new presentation?

Comment: Sorry, an $=$ sign should have been $\geqslant$. Corrected.

Comment: the first term is like u said converge to zero.
if i split  (n-Nc)/n i get n*c/n - N*c/n.
now, the mid term is converge to c and last term converge to zero because N is constant.

so i get bn>c and that's what i needed to find..?

Comment: Yes--since C can be as large as you want.